# Segmentation fault when performing an operation on a char which returns a value that exceeds 127

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, char

I tested the following code on two different computers, using gcc:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char c1, c2;
    c1 = 100;
    c2 = 4*c1;

    printf("%d", c2);
}
```

One of both tests threw a segmentation fault, the other outputted `-112`. Why did this happen ?

Comment: This code can't cause segmentation fault. Post the actual [mcve].

Comment: The maximum positive value of a `char` is 127.

Comment: It is 100% correct code except the integer overflow. But it can't cause the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Damien this does not really answer the question.

Comment: @user8171079. It was not an answer. It was a comment, trying to clarify what you want to do exactly. Comment are meant for that.

Comment: @user8171079 it answers the question considering the code posted. BTW this code can't "output" anything. Need to DV - you need to change your question

Comment: "the other outputted -112" --> code performs no output.  Best to post true code.

Comment: user8171079, If `char c1, c2;` is changed to `int c1, c2;`, does the "segmentation fault" remain?

Comment: `printf("%d", c2);` _maybe_ could cause a segmentation fault as it lacks a prior declaration.  Be sure to include `<stdio.h>`.  Tip:  save time, enable all warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me tell you, a plan `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, depends on the implementation.

That said, I think you understand it by now, trying to store a value into a type which may not be fit to handle that, is implementation defined behavior.

In most practical case, the stored value will be treated as the 2's compliment value (of a negative number), and be used as such, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: "the stored value will be treated as the 2's compliment value" does not well explain how `int` 400 became -112.  The `int` was certainly 2's compliment.  This is more of a lopping off bits issues or mod than a 2's compliment one.